# iRequired request part 'files' is not present in karate api testing

Tags: karate

when i try to use this below feature i am getting Required request part 'files' is not present
Feature: Verify that products are properly returned by the API

```
Background:
* url 'http://localhost:8080'

Scenario: Products are returned on post

Given path 'upload'
And multipart field files = read('test.txt')    
When method post
Then status 200
And match $ == {error: false, bytesUploaded:'#notnull'}
```

please suggest proper solution or alternative for file upload api test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the `multipart file` documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-file

```
Given path 'upload'
And multipart file files = { read: 'test.txt', filename: 'test.txt', contentType: 'text/plain' }
When method post
Then status 200
And match $ == { error: false, bytesUploaded: '#notnull' }
```